# Tkinter - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python

Necesito simplemente cambiar el texto de un Label despues de unos segundos usando Tkinter, pero me aparece el siguiente error: (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set').

```
import tkinter 

def fun_2():
    var.set('CAMBIO')

def fun():

    root.withdraw()

    root_2 = tkinter.Toplevel()

    aviso = tkinter.Label(root_2, textvariable = var)
    aviso.pack()

    aviso.after(7000, fun_2)

    root.after(8000, root.destroy)


root = tkinter.Tk()

var = tkinter.StringVar()
var = 'hola desde la v.secundaria'


boton = tkinter.Button(root, text='action', command=fun).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

No comprendo por que indica ese error si ya declare el StringVar() y se supone que set() debería poder establecer el valor string, ¿que hice mal?

Comment: Hola Jhonatan, precisamente lo que haces mal es que no usas el método `set` para asignar el nuevo valor justo después de instanciarla como si haces en `fun_2` correctamente: `var = 'hola desde la v.secundaria'` cuando debería ser `var.set('hola desde la v.secundaria')`.

Comment: Lo anterior causa que `var` pase a hacer referencia a un objeto `str`, por lo que cuando llamas a la función en `var.set("CAMBIO")` estás intentando usar el método `set` de un objeto `str`, (`'hola desde la v.secundaria'.set("CAMBIO")`), que obviamente no tiene, de ahí el error que te muestra. Dado que sabes de la existencia del método set y de su uso, supongo que en realidad es un error tipográfico más que nada.